# facebook open graph retrieve data retroactively

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

We have an app on facebook for login on our website.  I'd like to retrieve open graph data (simple things such as likes, interests, etc) combine it with our own database, to run some analysis to gage customer behavior.

I'm running into some issues with the auth token and it seems like even though the user approved the app, you cannot retroactively pull the customer data.  Is this correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean with "retroactively"? Give an actual example...

Comment: Do you get an error when you try to do it?

Comment: most importantly: is the app new? I mean, did you create it recently?

Answer (score 0):

To fetch data that occurred in the past (e.g. using a script) then you'll need to make use of **long term** access tokens. [Facebook's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) gives a great overview on how these work, but in short:

- Short term access tokens are usually perfect for actions the user takes while on your website/app.
- Long term access tokens are great for providing access to the user's profile when they're not actively logged in to your website/app (the short term access token will have expired & changed)

If you save a permanent access token for the user, you'll be able to pull data for all users retroactively.